# View all files in folders at once

Tags: macos

When using Finder, the files in my folders do not appear all at the same time. It says "see all" or "see less".

I would like to be able to see all files in my folders at once and make it a default. Anyone can advise me on how to make that change?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Right click in an empty spot in Finder and see if "Use Groups" is checked. If yes, select it to uncheck. This should disable the behavior.

Comment: You might want to change the `View as`. Shortcut is cmd + 1,2,3,4 for 4 different views.

Comment: Thanks for your response however I have no idea how to make those changes.

Comment: @PeterHorniak, what do you mean "see all files in my folders at once"? Can you edit your post to show a screenshot of what it looks right now?

Comment: @PeterHorniak Hi! Just as I used @<your username>, you should use it to ping the person you're trying to respond to, or I won't get the notification.  As to changing the settings, you should go to View menu(top left) in the Finder and see the first four options. They are different view options. For better explanation, See this apple support article's paragraph titled "Change how your files are displayed" https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201732

Comment: As for @NimeshNeema's comment, Use two-finger-single-tap in empty space in the finder to search for "use groups" in the menu that appears.